# Screen saver, Metro button and Windows key all stopped working together

Tags: windows-8.1

With no changes to my laptop that I am aware of, screen saver stopped kicking in. This is interesting in that policy prevents changes to any settings on the screen saver.

At the same time, the Start Button on the command bar that takes you to the Start Screen stopped taking me to the Metro screen. It flashes erratically when the mouse hovers over it and has no effect when clicked.

The Windows key on the keyboard likewise does not work.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or, at least, where to look?

EDIT:
Another item which seems relevant: during boot-up, before the login screen, there is a pop-up that asks whether I want to turn on "Toggle keys"

Comment: These all sound like the same problem to me, probably a key stuck down. Have you restarted the computer? Are other clicks giving you weird behaviors? You may want to try opening on-screen keyboard and toggling on/off Alt, windows key, shift, ctrl (the 'usual suspects').

Comment: Re-boot was the first thing I tried. Even a hard reset. I'm typing this on the machine in question. No problems with keyboard or mouse except what I described. Removed both the external keyboard and the mouse for testing anyway, no changes.

Comment: What exactly is the "Metro" button?  I have never seen a "GO" button on the command bar either.  I have used Windows 8 since release on ALL my machines.

Comment: @Ramhound, it is the "Windows" icon, leftmost on the command bar that takes you from the desktop to the Metro screen. It takes the place and some of the functionalty of the Windows 7 "Go" button.

Comment: @Metaphor - The technical name given to that "button" is the **start button** which takes you into the "Start Screen" in Windows 8 and the Start Menu in previous versions of Windows.  Its not called the "Go" button in ANY VERSION OF WINDOWS.

Comment: It was "Go" in some version. 95? Millenium? XP? Whatever, I hardly ever use it anymore and really never cared what it was called until it came time to describe it. Thank you for the correction. I just apologized to it and called it a "Start Button", it didn't help.